# How to return JSON data from php MongoCursor

Tags: php, mongodb

I am using PHP to connect with MongoDB. My code is as follows.

```
// connect
$m = new MongoClient($con_string); // connect to a remote host at a given port
$db = $m->main;

$customers = $db->customer->find();
```

i want to return $customers collection as json document to my HTML. How can i do this?

Comment: `foreach($customers as $k => $row){ $newa[] = json_encode($row); }` you may need to convert the object types to pure string first though like the `MongoId`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this two ways:

```
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($customers));
```

or you can manually scroll through it:

```
foreach($customers as $k => $row){
    echo json_encode($row);
}
```

Each of MongoDBs objects should have their `__toString()` methods correctly implemented to bring back the representation of the value.

Answer (score 8):

This also will work. And you can customize your json as well.

```
    $arr = array();

    foreach($customers as $c)
    {
        $temp = array("name" => $c["name"], "phone" => $c["phone"], 
                                            "address" => $c["address"]);
        array_push($arr, $temp);
    }

    echo json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: this solution is better because it adds the comma to the json.. +1

Comment: @ianaz The comma which separates multiple values from collection.

Comment: @Jack don't get it, it does the exact same as iterator to cursor, it forms an array of all rows and the json_encodes it

Answer (score 4):

Other answers work, but it is good to know that the generated JSON will have the following form (in this example I use an hypothetical "name" field for your customers):

```
{
    "5587d2c3cd8348455b26feab": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "5587d2c3cd8348455b26feab"
        },
        "name": "Robert"
    },
    "5587d2c3cd8348455b26feac": {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "5587d2c3cd8348455b26feac"
        },
        "name": "John"
    }
}
```

So in case you don't want the Object `_id` to be the key of each of your result objects you can add a `false` parameter to `iterator_to_array`.
Your code would be:

```
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($customers, false), true);
```

This creates the same result as

```
$result = Array();
foreach ($customers as $entry) {
    array_push($result, $entry);
}
echo json_encode($result, true);
```

which is an array of JSON objects

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "5587d2c3cd8348455b26feab"
        },
        "name": "Robert"
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$id": "5587d2c3cd8348455b26feac"
        },
        "name": "John"
    }
]
```