# MongoDB won't issue JSON file in PHP

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I make a query to my DB using PHP in the following way:

```
$foodCategory = $_POST["foodCategory"];
    if($foodCategory == "All") {
        $filter = [];
    } else {
        $filter = ["category" => $foodCategory];
    }
$options = [];
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$rows = $manager->executeQuery('posx.menu', $query);

echo(json_encode($rows));
```

I don't know why the function echos nothing, and to get it work I have to manually assemble the JSON file in the following way:

```
echo "[";
foreach ($rows as $document) {
    echo(json_encode($document));
    echo (", ");
}
echo "]";
```

Obviously, manually assembling JSON is not a good idea, therefore I decided to ask the question. Thanks for the help in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($rows));
```

[[How to return JSON data from php MongoCursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232261/how-to-return-json-data-from-php-mongocursor][1])

Comment: Sorry, write $row and not $rows. Maybe it work. I advise to you review the link and read this documentation [MongoDB Driver](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mongodb-driver-query.php)